# What is the difference between SOIC8E and SOIC8N?

Tags: integrated-circuit, surface-mount

What is the difference between these SMD packages? SOIC8E and SOIC8N?

Comment: With respect to what? Most package definitions are manufacturer specific. Please provide examples, and a few paragraphs of the research you've found. Before posting thoroughly research the question.

Comment: Hello. MP1584 and MP2307. Both has a thermal pad on the packside but MP1584 is SOIC8E and MP2307 is SOIC8N.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SOIC8E has an **E**xposed thermal pad. SOICN does **N**ot.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I think the monolithic power datasheet is bad, because they wrote that SOIC8N with exposed pad on the backside. [link](https://www.monolithicpower.com/DesktopModules/DocumentManage/API/Document/GetDocument?id=583)

Comment: @Bruk It wouldn't be the first datasheet with a significant error.